# Having issues replaying PCAP files with Pktgen-DPDK

Tags: dpdk

I'm having a hard time trying to replay PCAP files using pktgen.
I tried a couple different dpdk/pktgen versions (including the latest) and I'm experiencing the same behavior.

My setup:

- 1 VM running pktgen (Ubuntu 20.04, e1000 network card)
- 1 VM running l2fwd
- A small PCAP file, containing between 1 and 50 packets

Now, running pktgen, without trying to replay PCAP files works fine. The l2fwd app sees the network traffic.

```
./pktgen -c 3 -n 1 -- -T -m 1.0
```

If I try to replay PCAP files, pktgen stats shows it sent packets, but I see nothing on the l2fwd app.

```
./pktgen -c 3 -n 1 -- -T -m 1.0 -s 0:capture.pcap
```

Am I missing something ? Is there anything different when replaying PCAPs ?

Comment: Did you ever discover what happened?